# Server/Client Running with command line

Tags: java, command-line, client-server, command-line-arguments, main-method

I have a question regarding server/client running on the command line. The server should be run something like this

Server should run with a command line passing port number

java Server port_number

Client should run with command line as following format:

java Client serverIP  server_port_number commandFile

I was wondering if someone could show me an example of what the beginning of the "main method" should look like in both server/client to properly satisfy/take in these arguments when run on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ServerExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    System.out.println("Your first argument is: "+args[0]);  
    int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  }  
}
```

This will print port_number (as mentioned in the server execution).

```
class ClientExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
    System.out.println("Your first argument is: "+args[0]);
    System.out.println("Your second argument is: "+args[1]);
    System.out.println("Your third argument is: "+args[2]);
    String serverIP = args[0];
    int serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String commandFile = args[2];
  }  
}
```

This will print serverIP, server_port_number, and commandFile (as mentioned in the client execution).

Comment: May I know why the downvote?

Comment: o i see thanks for the help. Btw i don't think i downvoted. I will test this right now Edit: hey thanks it worked perfectly